# How to get from an R data.table to a list of matrices

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

[image]

How can I transform it into a list of matrices, where for each MV value, I have 3 matrices (consumption, dailySd and isAbsentBool) containing the elements of each time period (there are 178 periods in total):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `lapply`

```
lapply(as.list(unique(DF$mv)), function(x){return(as.matrix(DF[(mv==x), list(consumption, dailySd, period)]))})
```

first argument of `lapply` is unique list of mv values, second argument is a function that filters data.table, keeps relevant columns and convert it to matrix. `lapply` automatically loops over the list and returns list

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing this using `data.table::split`:

```
lapply(
    split(DT, by="mv", keep.by=FALSE),
    function(DT) DT[, as.matrix(.SD),
        .SDcols=c("consumption", "dailySd", "isAbsentBool")]
)
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(consumption=c(10,10,50,70),
    dailySd=c(1,2,3,4),
    isAbsentBool=c(0,0,0,0),
    mv=c("A.V1", "A.V1", "A.v2", "A.V3"),
    period=c(1,2,3,4))
```